# Numeric sort in Manual (Legacy) index in Neo4j 3 is not working correctly

Tags: neo4j, lucene

I'm using Legacy indexing (now called Manual indexing). After migration from Neo4j 2 to version 3 I have some problems with numeric sorting.

Example of correct statement in Neo4j 2:

```
queryContext.sort(new Sort(new SortField(AGE, SortField.INT, false)));
```

This stament should be changed for Neo4j 3 (Lucene 5):

```
queryContext.sort(new Sort(new SortField(AGE, SortField.Type.INT, false)));
```

But if you use this sort statement you will get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type SORTED_SET for field 'firstName' (expected=SORTED). Use UninvertingReader or index with docvalues.
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.checkField(DocValues.java:208)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.getSorted(DocValues.java:264)
at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparator$TermOrdValComparator.getSortedDocValues(FieldComparator.java:762)
at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparator$TermOrdValComparator.getLeafComparator(FieldComparator.java:767)
at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldValueHitQueue.getComparators(FieldValueHitQueue.java:183)
at org.apache.lucene.search.TopFieldCollector$SimpleFieldCollector.getLeafCollector(TopFieldCollector.java:164)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.collector.DocValuesCollector.replayTo(DocValuesCollector.java:297)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.collector.DocValuesCollector.getTopDocs(DocValuesCollector.java:275)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.collector.DocValuesCollector.getIndexHits(DocValuesCollector.java:150)
at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.legacy.LuceneLegacyIndex.search(LuceneLegacyIndex.java:346)
at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.legacy.LuceneLegacyIndex.query(LuceneLegacyIndex.java:261)
at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.legacy.LuceneLegacyIndex.query(LuceneLegacyIndex.java:205)
at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.legacy.LuceneLegacyIndex.query(LuceneLegacyIndex.java:217)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StateHandlingStatementOperations.nodeLegacyIndexQuery(StateHandlingStatementOperations.java:1440)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.nodeLegacyIndexQuery(OperationsFacade.java:1162)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.LegacyIndexProxy$Type$1.query(LegacyIndexProxy.java:83)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.LegacyIndexProxy.query(LegacyIndexProxy.java:365)
```

I think this is caused by new added statement in Neo4j indexer class (Neo4j is indexing field for sorting automatically now?). See in:

```
org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.legacy.IndexType CustomType addToDocument( Document document, String key, Object value )
```

new line:

```
document.add( instantiateSortField( key, value ) );
```

and method instantiateSortField is creating SortedSetDocValuesField

So I changed my code to:

```
queryContext.sort(new Sort(new SortedSetSortField(AGE, false)));
```

This runs OK but sorting is not working because numbers are sorted as string. I see that "value" parameter is String every time in method "addToDocument". I think the root cause is explained it this old comment:

```
see comment in class org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.legacy.IndexType CustomType
// TODO We should honor ValueContext instead of doing value.toString() here.
// if changing it, also change #get to honor ValueContext.
```

Am I missing some new way how to index, search and sort data in Neo4j 3 or this is really problem that values are indexed as string in Neo4j?

Simple unit test for Neo4j 2 and Neo4j 3 can be [downloaded](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/gYhAu)

Comment: Could you raise this with the content of your question and the links to your tests as a GH issue at github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues ?

Comment: added [GH issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/7216)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution added by MishaDemianenko at [GH issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/7216)